# C#-Pandas Process Error (.NET): no module named pandas

Tags: python, c#, pandas

I have a simple GUI with two buttons and a rich text box. Button One uses the OpenFileDialog() class to fetch a video file and write the path as a string in the rich text box. Button 2 takes the value of the rich text box and sends it file to a Python script. This part works fine. Here is the function for sending the file.

I am operating out of Visual Studio 19.

C# .NET framework

```
   public void PotatoOne(string path)
    {
        var neat = "r'" + path;
        var shell = "python.exe";
        Process x = new Process();
        x.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
        {
            FileName = shell,
            Arguments = ($"\"{"C:\\Users\\BeckerLab\\source\\repos\\Final Implementation\\Final Implementation\\untitled7.py"}\" \"{neat}\""),
            ErrorDialog = true,
            WorkingDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(@"C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow1"),
            UseShellExecute = false,
            CreateNoWindow = false,
            RedirectStandardError = true,
            RedirectStandardOutput = true
        };

        try
        {
            x.Start();
            var res = x.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
            var err = x.StandardError.ReadToEnd();

            Console.WriteLine(res);
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine(err);
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

BUT the Process says I do not have some of the modules. Here they all are:
(notably, os, sys, numpy and cv2 are all understood. pandas and PIL, are not)

Python Code, (attempted Anaconda3, tensorflow1 envs)

```
import os
import cv2 
import numpy as np
import sys
import pandas as pd
from pandas import ExcelWriter
from pandas import ExcelFile
import PIL
```

`path = sys.argv[1]`

I have untitled7.py in its own folder as a python file with its own solution, and they are both using the same Python environments, with the same module patches. Furthermore, untitled7.py has access to all the imports in the regular Python script, but not the .NET process.

It is clear that whatever I am doing, it's not calling the python file to run the same way. Is it because I am calling the Process incorrectly? Do I need to call a virtual environemt? Why can't I call the actual Python environment to run a Python script? Why does the exact same environment not provide the same set of modules for both solutions?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Correction: I have two copies of ```untitled7.py``` one is in its own solution, the other is a file attached to the main solution

Comment: have you considered compiling your python to an EXE, might simplify things

Comment: isnt it?. ```x.FileName = "python.exe";```